How could small animals survive a decade in this world?
Short version:
Living beings in this world take a decade to reach true diversity; how could the beings from rat to fox size live long enough for this? Is hibernation viable?
Long version:
In this earth-like world, all living beings fall into one of 16 categories (fungi, humanoids, mesoplants, macrobeasts, aquaplants, etc). Any offspring in a category starts off exactly identical to any other offspring in that category, and over the course of the next year (sometimes in an egg/womb/dormancy) it takes one of two paths. Perhaps a mesobeast (rat to fox size) either becomes more weasel-like or more rabbit-like. This continues forever - the next year, a weasel-like mesobeast may become more duck-like or more mole-like, and a rabbit-like mesobeast more squirrel-like or more frog-like. This is a pure coin flip, unaffected by any factors. This means something n years old has $2^n$ possible paths - albeit many are not suited to the environment, so most die even without being hunted. Because the first differentiation tends to be male/female, a "species" is one gender only, but I don't think that will be relevant.
The problem is, how do the mesobeasts (mid-sized animals, rat-fox size) survive to become sufficiently interesting? I want them to include a range of awesomeness similar to all Earth's mid-sized non-flying land animals, and it takes them at least ten years (1024 "species") to get there. Macrobeasts can shelter their young that long; microbeasts can grow for thirty years cicada-style; fungi can survive in the ground for a long time. But mice, squirrels, and rabbits don't usually live that long, and it's even worse for the first few years before they've adapted to their environment or died of bad fit. I can increase lifespan arbitrarily, but I assume real-world rabbits etc have such a short lifespan because it's not worth it to spend the resources to be able to live longer.
So how could they live ten years?
Hibernation might work. But if most mesobeasts hibernated for even half their lifespan, you'd get a great deal of predation on summer hibernators. Perhaps they could seal themselves in a den and shut down almost all air use, but if most mesobeasts can dig then it's not such an obstruction to others.
Pseudo-hibernation might work. Mesobeasts could optimize for a very low metabolic state, and hunt just enough meat/plants to survive, then huddle in their den with fierce fangs and claws, ready to fight, for another year. But that seems... silly, I guess. So different from how real-world mesobeasts work, and surviving to differentiate again isn't necessarily a positive good after reaching sexual maturity. Perhaps I could say that sexual maturity happens around year 3-6, so all mesobeasts must last quite a while, but I don't know if it would work anyway.
Having a lot of kids, disappointingly, does not seem to work. A fair portion of your kids will grow up to devour all the other kids; you can't really r-select if the biggest threat to your children is your other children. Mesobeasts will probably have a lot of kids anyway, but I don't think it's a solution.
Protecting your kids, opossum-style, might work for some, but I doubt it. For large beasts, yes. For small animals, it doesn't seem likely to work for more than the first year.
Late hibernation, where by year 3ish an mesobeast has developed a distinct niche, sounds the most promising; frog-likes hide in mud where most predators can't hunt, mole-likes burrow, squirrel-likes hide in barricaded tree cavities, and so on.
Is there a workable solution available on a large scale, preferably one with analogues in real-world nature, that lets at least a hundredth of mesobeasts live a decade?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

just out of curiosity why use this complicated mess instead of just having your creatures evolve normally? Or are you trying to ask how to  evolve X, in which case its very confusing what your asking.

@John Fair enough - thank you, I'm often blind to how confusing my questions are. I have the freedom to declare what each path is at the start, but nothing evolves in this world, and paths don't change (though there is utterly baseless speculation that when no creature has a given path, it changes itself).

To answer your first question, I made it specifically because, well, our world is a mess, with little bits of genetics everywhere changing how living beings think and act and look, and no proper uniformity. So I wanted something with both uniformity and ridiculous diversity, and powers of 2 are beautiful. This way 3-year-olds are very often identical, 7-year-olds know of 1 person who is identical to them, and 30-year-olds are unique in all the world - but still have visible "racial" characteristics developed when 5 that everyone recognizes. The odd effects are downstream of what I wanted.

The short version has insufficient information to be comprehensible. A reader needs information from the long version for the short version to make sense.

Why not have the amount of diversification time be a percentage of the average lifespan? That would even 'organically' make sense.

@Joachim Well, really, because it solves all my problems; a constrained world is more interesting than one where I just take the obvious step to simplify it. But also, if it's based on average lifespan I can't say that humans differentiate every year exactly, because that would be silly arbitrary; that way I don't get yearly birthdays/differentiation completion days, which I would like.

Whatever they turn into there's a predator that eats that.
Whatever they turn into, there's a poison that kills that predator.
There are many (if not most) creatures that engage in display behaviours (I'm counting colour/markings as display here). Poisonous frogs are brightly coloured - the effect being to signal to predators that they're poisonous. There are creatures that have similarly evolved to look like poisonous creatures, exhibiting the same colour patterns, and similar behaviour when they're threatened. This masquerade serves them well to preserve their lineage.
Other creatures in your world would need to be poisonous for this to work - in the event that that's not the case, then a slightly different strategy needs to apply:
A behavioural display:
This is likely to take the form of a loud warning cry/bark/squeal, coupled with making itself bigger, more imposing/impressive. Whatever it is it should have a visceral effect on the listener, a fearful sound. This warns the predator: A) They are poisonous. B) They are prepared to fight back like a mad thing and there are friends nearby that their cry has put on notice of a predator's presence.
Safety in numbers:
Herd behaviour. To accommodate the various diverse members, the group should visit the food supply of each in turn. This would lead to resource-dependent migration in a complex way, more than deer or bison currently do. The group can be relied on to circle facing-outward with the longest teeth showing. A solo or group of predators should be easily put off - predator numbers should not generally be larger than a fraction of group/herd. This wouldn't prevent ambush predation, or poison-stings that kill after time, then the abandoned body would be eaten.

Hmm, thank you. Optimizing for producing high-powered defences - or just pretending to - more than most real-world animals for the first few years. That works... better than I had anticipated.

And I feel silly for not thinking of the other obvious solution in retrospect - just make mesobeast-hunting mesobeasts rare, only 1/32 or 1/64 of the population, and not crazy high-powered energy-burners like shrews.
